# Problema no tamanho dos checkboxes do HTML

Tags: html5, css3, checkbox

Estou com um problema no tamanho dos meus checkboxes, cada um está ficando com um tamanho diferente do outro. Eu isolei a ul com uma classe, para que esse elemento não pegasse nenhuma característica das outras uls para as quais eu já havia definido um estilo. Alguém saberia dizer porquê os checkboxes estão ficando com tamanhos diferentes? E como eu poderia resolver isso. Segue o print da página e o código para vcs vizualizarem o problema: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}




section#principal {
    width: 100%;
}

section#principal .modulo .container {
    height: ;
    padding: 20px;
}

section#principal .modulo .container .canvas {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
}

form ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #161616;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.confirmacoes li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
}

.confirmacoes input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projeto 008</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0e1b97932.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>                        
 
 <section id="principal">
    
     <div class="modulo">
          
        <div class="container">
            <div class="canvas">
                
                <form action="">                     
                                      
                    <h2>Anythings</h2>
                    <ul class="confirmacoes">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <label>Güncelleme ve yenilikleri mail olarak almak istiyorum.</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id nisl eget nunc molestie maximus.</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                                       
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
     </div>
     
 </section>
                   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de `display: flex` em `.confirmacoes li`?

Comment: Para fazer o alinhamento do checkbox com o label. Tá errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox está variando de tamanho de acordo com o tamanho do texto. Se você aumentar suficientemente o texto da primeira checkbox, ela fica menor do que a segunda.

Isso ocorre por causa do `display: flex` no seu CSS para `.confirmacoes li`. Caso queira manter isso, a minha sugestão é utilizar `min-width` e `min-height` no seu CSS:

```
.confirmacoes input {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Dessa forma o navegador entende que não deve utilizar menos de 20px para largura e altura da checkbox, mesmo com o `display: flex` no elemento `li` que contém a checkbox.

Comment: Testei o que vc me passou, os tamanhos dos checkboxes ficaram iguais, mas não estão respondendo ao width, height e margin indicados, o checkbox ficou com outro tamanho e as margens tbm.

Comment: @Alineat com o li tendo `display:flex`, o input não obedecerá as instruções `height` nem `width`

Comment: É verdade, eu tirei o display: flex e parou de acontecer. Obrigada.